# backup/restore openrdf-sesame repository in production

Tags: sesame, rdfstore

I use openrdf-sesame memoryStore(persist) and native store as my data stores.

Whats the standard/recommended way of backup/restore my datastores?

Is there any supported api?

I run sesame standalone server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite easily create something yourself, just by using `RepositoryConnection.export`. However, there are also a few ready-made (commandline) tools available, for example this simple [sesame-backup](https://bitbucket.org/insightng-ondemand/sesame-backup) tool (disclaimer: I developed that). Download, install, and stick in a cronjob to have it make regular scheduled backups.

Comment: Hi Jeen...thanks for this...could u also tell me how do you make your sesame severs high available?

Comment: If you want to thank me, vote up and/or accept the answer :)

As for your followup question: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: For eg. in mongo/mysql...we can setup replication which does auto failover which makes them high available. But I am not sure how can accomplish the same with jetty/sesame combination...I do not want to run prod with only 1 jetty/sesame server. If that does down its not good...I can do backups but that will not make it high available

Comment: That would be a feature of the actual backend store you use. Sesame's built-in stores (native, memory) have no clustering support. But several 3rd-party Sesame stores, such as Ontotext's OWLIM, do support this. There's also some ongoing work on providing a Cassandra backend for Sesame, but that's in early stages of development.

Comment: thanks...for now I am protecting jetty servers with lot of caching...I will switch to different store soon.